# Which kind of technique is used for classifying a graph datastructure?

Tags: neural-network, graphs

I have a 3D surface from which I extract certain spatial parameters like extremas and their locations (a.k.a coordinates), which then I convert into a bipartite graph with distance between them as edges. Now, using MST, I reduce it to a tree.

This end structure is supposed to represent a lower dimensional version of the above surface. Now, I assign a label to the graph (actually, I get two graphs for 1 label)

I need to pass this data set to a supervised classifier to get an output. But, CNNs and RNNs seem not to work on graph data. Is there a way to input Graph and get a classified label?

Comment: Could you share an example of the initial data? Why do you want to use a graph first to classify? I ask this because in some cases, you can directly classify without going through a graph.

Comment: I wanted to make it into a graph because it is really memory intensive.

Comment: @NicolasM https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97555/how-to-model-a-3d-graph-into-a-vector-so-that-i-can-feed-it-into-a-classificatio

Comment: @NicolasM my other question is about that. I flattened it into a 2D image from top view. Which I passed into a CNN with labels, it was really memory intensive and I kept filling my disk because I was using memory mappings and they were overflowing in RAM.

Comment: Also, I'll share the data when I get home as I don't have internet access to my workstation  in office.

Comment: Do you intend to classify your graphs/3D images like the MNIST dataset? If yes, and if every graph contains lot of data, you should reduce the data volume, maybe by using a tesselation of your 3D shapes. Very often, you don't need to be precise about the minimum or the maximum values, but you have to find the good precision to avoid losing important information. Remember that you can use dimensional reduction techniques (TSNE/UMAP) that don't require a lot of memory. On the other hand, you have also 3D CNN to classify 3D data. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D